# Laravel 5 relationships hasOne save()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables **Projects** and **Galleries**. Project has one gallery. In galleries table I have a foreign key *project_id*.

```
Schema::table('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer("project_id")->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);

            $table->foreign("project_id")
                    ->references("id")
                    ->on("projects")
                    ->onDelete("set null");

        });
```

In Project model I have a function that gets the gallery associated with the project:

```
public function gallery()
  {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Gallery");
  }
```

When creating new project, user selects from drop down the gallery then when saving a new project, how can I update galleries table to use newly created projects_id

```
$gallery_id = 2; // user selected gallery 2

$project = new Project();
$project->title = "new project";
$project->save();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$gallery_id = 2; // user selected gallery 2

$project = new Project();
$project->title = "new project";
$project->save(); 

$gallery = Gallery::find($gallery_id);
$gallery->project_id = $project->id;
$gallery->save();
```